# Как узнать, какая ос основная?

Tags: linux, windows, ос

На ноутбуке стоят две ос - windows и linux, загружаются через boot-менеджер при включении. Первая по приоритету - linux ubuntu. Она и является основной?

Comment: Что значит "основная" ОС? Наверное, "основная" -- это та, которой вы пользуетесь чаще всего.

Comment: Если вопрос в том, как поменять приоритет, то зависит от бут-лоадера. В systemd можно просто `d` нажать на нужной строчке или вручную отредактировать конфигурационный файл

Comment: Обе ОС совершенно равноправны. Просто одна - загружается по умолчанию, а для загрузки другой требуется подвигать руками.

Comment: спасибо, последний комментарий помог мне

Comment: @Akina почитал маны по systemd-boot, но так и не нашёл, что можно пропустить задание default entry. Правда ли, что какая-то система **должна** загружаться по-умолчанию, или возможно ещё большее равноправие без выбора системы по-умолчанию в systemd-boot или каком-то другом загрузчике?

Comment: @dIm0n Ну теоретически можно сделать тайм-аут загрузки дефолтной системы экстремально большим - по факту это и будет "ждать бесконечно, пока юзер не выберет". Но какой-то дефолтный пункт всё равно будет - курсор-то должен быть, а быть он может только на каком-то пункте из имеющихся.